# Is it possible to have multiple forms open at the same time in Extjs Modern framework?

Tags: extjs

We have a rich application with 341 Ext.window.Window screens written using Ext.js 7.0 Classic framework.  The user can have many screens open at the same time within the app.  In our code we make heavy use of win.getPosition(), win.setPosition() and the Ext.WindowManager to manage the windows, positioning them on the screen, maximizing them, minimizing them etc.  We want to modernize this app so we are looking at the Modern framework, but I cannot see how to have multiple screens (panels/forms) open at the same time and to manage their location and size.  My question is can this be done in the Modern framework and can anyone point to a sample app that demonstrates this capability?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the dialog class. https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.Dialog.html

Answer (score 1):

HWSW seems to have provided the answer in his comment.

"Take a look at the dialog class. docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.Dialog.html"

If anyone has a map of Classic class equivalents in Modern that would be AWESOME.